# Tangent space to the space of holomorphic structures

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, connections

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $E$ be a $C^\infty$ complex vector bundle over it, endowed with a Hermitian metric $h$. We can consider the space of all possible holomorphic structures on $E$, encoding these as Dolbeault operators $\bar{\partial}_E:\Omega^{p,q}(E)\rightarrow \Omega^{p,q+1}(E)$ (that satisfy the Leibniz rule and such that $\bar{\partial}_E^2 = 0$.

In the paper I am reading it is stated that (as a infinite-dimensional Banach manifold), the space of such structures $\mathcal{E}$ has as tangent space at any $\bar{\partial}_E$
$$
T_{\bar{\partial}_E}\mathcal{E} = \Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))
$$
I would like to know how can I prove this. I have barely started reading about infinite dimensional manifolds and I don't know if the approach "parametrize with $t$ and differentiate" which I usually take in finite dimensions is enough.

Comment: I have solved it by realizing that $\mathcal{E}$ is an affine space. I have edited the questions for typos: the tangent space is supposed to be $\Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))$ (which reduces to (0,1) forms when $E$ is a line bundle).

To see why note that given two Dolbeault operators their difference is a linear endomorphism on sections: $(\bar{\partial}_1 - \bar{\partial}_2) (fs) = f (\bar{\partial}_1 - \bar{\partial}_2)(s)$. Therefore the tangent space is precisely the space of $End(E)$-valued (0,1)-forms.

This does not address my concern: how to calculate tangent spaces in $\dim=\infty$?